# How to focus a specific element in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, accessibility

I'm doing accessibility work and testing tab focus.

Is there an easy way skip focus to a specific element on chrome or any other browser? For example, there is a button in the middle of the page. How can I quickly focus that element without tabbing through everything before it first?

Comment: Your question is somewhat ambiguous: is it about how you as a user or tester can quickly reach a specific part of a page or about how you as a developer can make sure that a user/tester can quickly reach a specific part of a page? Also, does that button have an id, is it part of a form or does is just exist on its own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the focus method in JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('myButton') .focus();
```

The focus method exists on all elements that are naturally focusable (like buttons, links, form elements), or that have been made focusable with the tabindex attribute.

For input elements, you can also use the autofocus attribute to tell the browser to focus it as soon as the page is loaded.

Comment: Definitely do not do this for anything other than testing purposes. Or, rather, do not deploy this for general users.

Comment: Definitely don't listen to @aardrian statement above. There are scenarios where using `focus()`  is perfectly fine, such as building accessible web interfaces in compliance with WCAG 2.1

Answer (score 1):

Many websites use "skip links" for the ability to bypass lengthy navigation menus and quickly access the certain areas of the page. This is useful for end-users as well as developers who are testing webpages.

The basic principle is that you'll have invisible links at the very beginning of the page that use anchor elements and IDs (just like any in-page link).

For example:

```
<body>
<a href="#maincontent">Skip to main content</a> 
...
<main id="maincontent">
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>This is the first paragraph</p>
```

WebAIM has a very good tutorial on this.
http://webaim.org/techniques/skipnav/

When you visit their site, press the `TAB` key before doing anything else, and you'll see an example of how this works.

I would consider this method to be more reliable than using JavaScript, as HTML is more widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

- Open chrome developer tools

Inside the console, you can focus any element using the following:

```
 document.querySelector(selector).focus();
```

- The selector can be obtained right clicking the element inside the code of the developer tools and selecting `copy / copy selector`

This does not required the element to have an `id` attribute, but you still can use it.